# Ractive.js, missing values and nested with

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I have a rather large, deep and diverse data model with no guarantees about what it will contain or not. Ractive is usually pretty chill about keypaths not leading anywhere, and simply evaluates them to `undefined`, which makes it easy to set up defaults:

```js
r = new Ractive({
  template: '#template',
  el: '#el',
  data: {
    foo: {
      ok: {
        bar: "okay",
      },
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ractive"></script>
<script id="template" type="text/ractive">
    {{#with {
      ok: foo.ok.bar || "not found",
      notok: foo.notok.bar || "not found"
    } }}
      OK: {{ok}}
      <br>
      NotOK: {{notok}}
    {{/with}}
</script>

<div id="el"></div>
```

But add another layer of indirection, and the whole thing breaks apart:

```js
r = new Ractive({
  template: '#template',
  el: '#el',
  data: {
    foo: {
      ok: {
        bar: "okay",
      },
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ractive"></script>
<script id="template" type="text/ractive">
  {{#with {
    okKey: "ok",
    notokKey: "notok"
  } }}
    {{#with {
      ok: foo[okKey].bar || "not found",
      notok: foo[notokKey].bar || "not found"
    } }}
      OK: {{ok}}
      <br>
      NotOK: {{notok}}
    {{/with}}
  {{/with}}
</script>

<div id="el"></div>
```

The entire `with` section fails to render, and the console gets a warning:

> Failed to compute @{ok:foo[@{okKey:"ok",notokKey:"notok"}.okKey].bar||"not found",notok:foo[@{okKey:"ok",notokKey:"notok"}.notokKey].bar||"not found"}: Cannot read property 'bar' of undefined

Is this a bug, or a desired behaviour? Any way to get around it? My paths are very deep, and it would be excruciating to have to check every single evaluation with `{{#if bar in foo}}{{#if baz in foo[bar]}}{{#if quux in foo[bar][baz]}} {{foo[bar][baz][quux]}} {{/if}}{{/if}}{{/if}}`.

Comment: You need to move things around a bit: '{{#with { okKey: "ok", notokKey: "notok"} }} {{#with { ok: foo[.okKey], notok: foo[.notokKey] } }} OK: {{.ok.bar || "not found"}}<br>NotOK: {{.notok.bar || "not found"}} {{/with}}  {{/with}}'